# If I need to update the InfoPath's XML File in sharepoint? Is it possible to do it? 

Tags: infopath, forms-services, xml, windows-server

I'm very new at SharePoint, please forgive my stupid questions or mistake....

Currently I'm in the process of updating the SharePoint Server. I would like to update the InfoPath Form in SharePoint (add three new fields to it and keep all the fields that contain in the old one). And one of the problem I'm facing is that the old information will have those three new fields the fields will be blank.

By solving that I would like to read the relative fields in the XML and take the first 200 words or less and append those to the new field. (I'm not too sure if it is possible but I'm currently testing it).

For example in the old form I have a field called: "Description" and I create a new field called "Summary Description". I would like to read the first 200 words in description and append to summary description.

This is what I can do so far. I'm able to extract all the XML Files (about 500 files) and read all the relevant fields.

**And my problem is how do I re-upload those XML files to SharePoint and re-link them after I upload it, assuming that I'm able to add new XML fields to the old one.**

Is this the right approach or I'm over thinking it? Or I should somehow figure out how to read the database that associate the SharePoint.

Everything I'm doing is in the test server. I'm using SharePoint Office 2007 and Window Server 2003 if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot give you advise on your specific issue, however, I was in your situation that an existing form should be updated. Until now I was able to aviod what you are trying to do.

I prefer to update the form and publish it to another location. After that the old library will be set to read-only and the new form will be used.

Don't know if that is helpful for you but I wouldn't like to manupulate every XML for every form update.